# Find the probability of queue not stopping due to the lack of change

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Consider the queue of size $2n$ that goes to the cash register. Each person in the queue have, with equal probability, either a coin worth 5 bucks or a coin worth 10 bucks, and wants to buy a ticket. The ticket costs 5 bucks. In total, there are $2m$ coins in the cash register, 5 bucks each.

1. Find the probability of the queue *not stopping* due to the lack of change.
2. What if $ m = 0$?

Honestly, I don't even know where to start. I assumed it's a variation of [Bertrand's ballot theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_ballot_theorem#Variant:_ties_allowed). 
We might assume that we start from $(0, 2m)$ grid point with probable step $(+1, -1)$. I guess we should calculate the possible ways to reach $(0, 0)$ from $(0, 2m)$, which is 
$$\frac{1}{2m-1}\frac{1}{2^{2m}}{{2m}\choose{m}}$$
But here we don't take anything given in the  task into consideration. How to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer. I think I know how to do in case $m = 0$

Probability queue will stop at first person = $\frac{1}{2}$

Probability queue will stop at $k = 2$  = $0$. Because we know that queue didn't stop at first person, so there must be 5$ in cash.

Probability queue will stop at $k = 3$ = $\frac{1}{2}^2$. Because before 3rd person comes there is equal probability of having $2$ 5 dollars or $0$. Multiplying it by probability that 3rd person has no 5dollar we get $\frac{1}{4}$

Probability queue will stop at $k = 4$ = $0$

And so on we get $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}^2 + ... + \frac{1}{2}^n$